# inside flex box not able align at end for label with pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In below snippet i have the tool name and same row one radio button also, But even though i have given `space-between` but the radio button is not at the end.

How can i align the radio button to the end of right side like how normally the `space-between` works

```css
.container-section-column-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: -5rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: border-color 400ms ease;
}

label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: -5rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label::before {
  border-color: red;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label::after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.55);
}
```

```html
<div class='container-section'>
  <div class='container-section-column-wrapper'>
    <div class='column-one'>
      <div class='tool-name'>Tool one</div>
    </div>
    <div class='column-two'>
      <input type='radio' id='tool-one' name='tool-pick-group' />
      <label for='tool-one' />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: FYI-- Unrelated to your question, but much of what you have here is fully inaccessible to assistive technologies. Perhaps this is something you intend to fix in your production code, but as this is currently written you're implementing some form accessibility anti-patterns...

Comment: The flex item containing your modified checkbox is properly positioned, but then you move the circle, via css, `left: -5rem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` are absolutely positioned in a relatively positioned parent (`label`). You are specifying `left: -5rem;` to try and align back further left which is causing the spacing you see. Instead, just use `right: 0;`.

```css
.container-section-column-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: border-color 400ms ease;
}

label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label::before {
  border-color: red;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label::after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.55);
}
```

```html
<div class='container-section'>
  <div class='container-section-column-wrapper'>
    <div class='column-one'>
      <div class='tool-name'>Tool one</div>
    </div>
    <div class='column-two'>
      <input type='radio' id='tool-one' name='tool-pick-group' />
      <label for='tool-one' />
    </div>
  </div>
```